# Why does Iterator::all return true for an empty iterator?

Tags: rust

The following code

```
fn main() {
    {
        let a: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
        print!("{}\n", a.into_iter().all(|x| x > 1));
    }
    {
        let a: Vec<i32> = vec![];
        print!("{}\n", a.into_iter().all(|x| x > 1));
    }
}
```

gives me the output

```
false
true
```

Surprisingly, `a.into_iter().all(|x| x > 1)` returned `true` when `a` is empty.

Looking at [the docs for `Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all), I see that it is explicitly stated:

> An empty iterator returns true.

Why was it chosen to be this way?

Comment: See [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the typical convention of the `all` function in pretty much all programming languages, except those that get it wrong. Conversely, `any` returns `false` for empty sequences.

The reason is that it is more useful for typical scenarios. If you have a list of requirements and a value must fulfill *all* of these to pass through a filter. If your list is actually empty, should the value get through? The answer that usually makes the most sense is yes. Therefore, `conditions.all(|value| condition.fulfilled(value))` returns `true` for the empty list.

It is also a natural consequence of the reformulation of the `all` definition as, "no item is false", and the default if you implement `all` in the intuitive way:

```
fn all<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> bool
where
    F: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool,
{
    for v in self {
        if !f(v) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There might even be a basis in mathematics for this, but I couldn't find something quickly.

Comment: `all` is basically folding with `&&` and since the identity element for `&&` is `true` it is what gets returned by `all`. `any` on the other hand is a fold with `||` and the identity for `||` is `false`.

Comment: Another example of the identity property being used: imagine writing `all` with `fold` or `reduce`. `self.fold(true, |acc, cur| acc && f(cur))`

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in the mathematical basis, here is a short proof:

The statement `A => B` (A implies B) is logically equivalent to `!A | B` (not A or B).

The statement `S`: `for each x in X, P(x) is true` (where P is a predicate) is a shorthand for `for each x: x in X implies P(X) is true`.

This statement is hence equivalent to: `For each x: P(x) is true or x is not in X`

If `X` is empty, the statement `x is not in X` is always true so the statement `S` is true.

Comment: Someone proposed an edit `For each x: P(x) is` ***true*** `or x is not in X`. It might be confusing but there si no mistake. `A=>(P(x) is true)` is equivalent to `not(P(x) is true) or A`. The ***not*** is important for this logic to be true

Comment: That someone would be me, and I'm afraid that the logic is *not* true. That's because the statement `A=>B` is logically equivalent to `B|!A` and not `!B|A` as written in the answer. The *location* of the `not` is important.

Comment: Whooops, indeed, then I will also correct my first line of logic where I introduce the error

Answer (score 1):

It is useful in mathematics for composability:

`any(x + y) == any(x) or any(y)`

`all(x + y) == all(x) and all(y)`

These conditions hold for all non-empty `x`, `y`. The values for empty `x` and `y` are chosen to maintain this property:

`all([]) == true`

`any([]) == false`

Comment: This is only half an answer. You should explicitly include where `all([]) == True` fits into the decomposition of `x + y` into separate `x` and `y`.

Comment: (It might be obvious to *you*, but it is not necessarily obvious to someone who doesn't understand why `all([])` should be true in the first place.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).